# Htaccess single page redirect problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having some issues setting up single page redirects using htaccess. Currently I have a htaccess file with:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then a set of redirects e.g.

```
Redirect 301 /oldpage.htm http://www.mydomain.com/new-page
```

But the problem I am having is that  when I go into a browser and type in the old URL, I get redirected to URL with a parameter attached, e.g:

"http://www.mydomain.com/new-page?path=oldpage.htm"

For some of my redirects this seems to work anyway, for some it produces a 404 error. I've also tried using RewriteCond and Rewrite Rule to write more generic catch all redirects for those pages that I can, and I'm having the same issue.

I'm thinking that some other rule must be interfering with my redirects - the only one I can see which might do so is the rule above, but if that was the case shouldn't the URL I am redirected to end up being

"http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?path=oldpage.htm"

Can anyone explain why parameters are being appended to the URLs and how I can stop this happening so that my redirects work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because mod_alias (the `Redirect` directive) and mod_rewrite (the `Rewrite*` directives) are both being applied to the same URI in the URL-file mapping processing pipeline. In order to keep this from happening, you need to stick with one or the other in this case.

You also want the redirect to get applied first:

```
RewriteRule ^/?oldpage.htm$ http://www.mydomain.com/new-page [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Your `index.php` rule is going to catch all requests that aren't CGI scripts that are symlinks, so, pretty much everything if that's really your intention. Otherwise you can let legit requests get by unscathed by including:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Above the last rule.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Lin - that seems to work. I'm not the original author of the site, so I haven't really worked out what the second Rewrite rule (index.php?path=$1) is supposed to be doing and why it is necessary.

Comment: @SunChild It looks like it routes "virtual requests" for some kind of CMS or framework. By virtual I mean, a request for something like `http://your.domain.com/some/path/page-name`, there's not folder `/some/` or `/some/path`, so the URI `/some/path/page-name` gets routed to `index.php` who then figures out how to serve the content for `page-name`. The `some/path` but could be categories, for example.

Answer (score 0):

because your $1 in rewrite rule

RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L] try this

Comment: I've tried editing the rule as you suggest, or infact just removing the rule entirely - but I still seem have to get the same effect.

Comment: I checked your original file on my localhost it's worked perfectly as you want. no any ?path= appends